# Questions tagged with Polymer but were using old version of Polymer

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There are many questions tagged with the main [polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer) tag before Polymer 1.0 was released (when Polymer was still in beta). In Polymer 1.0, [quite a lot of APIs and features have been changed](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html) and the old code will not work in Polymer 1.0 without significant changes in some areas.

To avoid confusion to the readers, I believe the tag [polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer) in questions that were referring to Polymer 0.5 to be changed to [polymer-0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polymer-0.5). By querying questions that were asked before Polymer 1.0 was released, we can filter out those that are outdated.

I'm not sure if this is under [retag-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request), however I sure know this request is reasonable.

Comment: Should there be a new tag for every release?

Comment: @JoeW Well as I pointed out, there's a huge change in its API, moreover, one is still in beta and one is not.

Comment: What I mean is when an updated version of a language is released does it need a new tag? Doesn't that just lead to fragmentation of the knowledge since it will be spread across multiple tags? Not sure why the fact that it was in beta and now is not matters for the tags. You would lose the benefits of people having a tag badge if you create a new tag for the beta version and one for the 1.0 version.

Comment: This doesn't lead to fragmentation of knowledge because it simply can't carry over. Users will try to understand the solutions posted in these question just to find out in a later stage that they don't work. Also don't we always create a new tag for big updates for languages such as [tag:ecmascript], [tag:ecmascript-5] and [tag:ecmascript-6], etc that aren't compatible with its former version?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to add a [tag:polymer-1.0] tag since polymer 1.0 is not even a month old yet.  like what the C++ tags did when we finally  for C++11

Comment: @NathanOliver The problem with that is that users tend to add [tag:polymer] instead of [tag:polymer-1.0] to their questions. On the other hand we can just add/replace with [tag:polymer-0.5] to old questions and be done with it.

Comment: Do it backwards, polymer is always the newer version, you always assume the newest version while answer it. *New* questions about the old version which don't apply to the new version, get the old version tag. Through, being truthful, I don't think the effort is worth it. It should be mentioned somewhere in the question body, not in the tags themselves.